# Using file uploaded to google's Colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

In google colab i am using this code to submit a ephemeral file:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

Then i am using this code to read the file I just submited:

```
with open('edges.txt') as f:
    mylist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
    newlist = []
    for line in mylist:
        line = line.split(',')             
        line[1], line[2] = line[2], line[1] 
        line = ','.join(line)               
        print(line)
        newlist.append(line)
```

What a I want is to use a generic name as `uploaded` in the `with open(uploaded)` line because not always the file's name will be edges.txt.

Ho can I do this?  I tried to use `uploaded` but it didn´t work.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the file as well as its contents will be in the `uploaded` variable, so there's no need to read the file again after upload.

Here's a full example:

[image]

The key bit is the `for name, contents in f.items()` line. `files.upload` returns a dict, with keys corresponding to the file names of items selected in the file picker. Dict values are the file contents.